# Cloning gerrit project onto my host

Tags: docker, gerrit, network-security

I am running gerrit on docker. I got the image from dockerhub.  I am running it this way:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 --rm 
-e AUTH_TYPE='DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT'
-v /home/gerrit-site:/home/gerrit/site
-v /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub:/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
-v /root/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa
-v /home/accounts/ssh-keys/:/home/gerrit/ssh-keys
--name gerrit docker.io/fabric8/gerrit:latest
```

The image is running and I can access it through the url i.e. ip:8080 .When i try to any project created via http it works and i get a cloned repo on my host. But when I try cloning via ssh, I get the following error,

```
 Cloning into 'project'...
 ssh: connect to host host_ip port 29418: Connection refused
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Later I also tried, adding my host ssh key into gerrit and tried cloning with no success.

When I try ssh ip:29418,

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip:29418: Name or service not known
```

I dont know where I am going wrong and would need some guidance.

Comment: attach please `ls -al` output in your .ssh directory

Comment: I manually deleted the the corresponding mapping of ip and key in known_hosts in  .ssh folder after which the a new mapping was made. Since then it started working.